# Jss not recognized as internal or external command while running in C#

Tags: jss, powershell-extensions, sitecore-api

I am calling a batch file via c# using powershell library, I see the below error

'jss' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Whereas manually executing the batch file runs with no issues.

### c#

```
 using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powershell.AddCommand("c:\\test.bat", true);
            Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
            PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord> error = powershell.Streams.Error;
            if (error.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < error.Count; i++)
                {

                }

            }
        }
```

### Batch file

cd C:\Projects\FirstJss

jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary --acceptCertificate

### Error

'jss' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`JSS` command line is an part of `@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli` `npm` package. It means that rules on how to run it are exactly the same as for other `npm` packages.

You need either:

- Install `@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli` globally by execution `npm i @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli -g`

or:

- Installed `@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli` to the directory, where you run your script. Change dir to `C:\Projects\FirstJss` and install it there `npm i @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli`

Comment: Thanks @Anton, I applied the fix both globally and locally, It works fine when I click the bat file manually or run those commands via cmd prompt, but while executing it via code its throwing the same exception "jss is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: @sns Are you able to run `jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary --acceptCertificate` from Powershell?

Comment: Anton , I can run it with Powershell with no issues.

Comment: Powershell script works fine if I trigger it manually, but when I  run it through code it is throwing the same error “Jss is not recognized”

Comment: @sns it could mean that you call Powershell using not the same user that you use for C# code execution. You can 1) either run your code by the same user or 2) you can install JSS CLI locally in a folder, where you are executing your code or 3) you can install JSS CLI for user that you use for C# code execution.